# Kubuntu: Black diagonal line across the screen

Tags: kubuntu, tearing, visual-artifacts, system-requirements

Total noob. Installed kubuntu on an old laptop to learn how to use it.I've got his dark shape across my desktop and Firefox. It will change size and shape.

See attached.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: What release of Kubuntu (I'm wondering what age your software stack is)  Has it always been there? or just appeared?  Do anything different in current session, or session before it appeared?  Video card details maybe useful to.

Comment: Only on Firefox? All the time? Give us some info of your setup with `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80`. Might help to use a newer driver with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`

Comment: Just installed it tonight, version 19.10. hp pavilion dv9700AMD Turionx2, 64bit.NVIDIA Graphics. OS updated as soon as installed. The anomaly appears on the desktop as well as Firefox, and changes size, shape and location.

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem. The LCD display is bad. Does pressing your thumb on the display change where/how the line appears?

Comment: No, physically touching the screen has no effect, but it does move around and change shape as I do things like move the mouse and click on things such as application launcher.

I tried to update drivers like Pablo suggested, but after I type in the command in Konsole, it won't let me type in the password; typing at that point has no effect. I suspect there is something simple that I'm not doing or doing wrong.

Comment: I also tried to get the info with : inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80 as suggested, but but don't know what to do with:

Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install inxi

Comment: System:Host: mike-HP-Pavilion-dv9700-Notebook-PC Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.16.5 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) Machine:Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion dv9700 Notebook PC v: Rev 1 serial:<rootrequired> Mobo: Quanta model: 30D1 v: 85.26 serial:<rootrequired>BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v:F.30date04//2008Graphics:Device-1: NVIDIA C67 [GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M] driver: nouveau v: kernel Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: nouveauunloaded:fbdev,modesetting,vesaresolution: 1440x900~60Hz OpenGL: renderer: NV67 v: 2.1 Mesa 19.2.1

Comment: Updated drivers, no change.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the desktop effects.  That worked for me